# indexing data to solr update url from python code in json format does not update the record in solr

Tags: python, json, solr, lucene

i am using a python function to index data to solr on localhost my code is below

```
import urllib
import urllib2

def indexSolrVenue():
    url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/venue/update/json?commit=true&wt=json'
    data = '[{"id":"3","title":"allen"}]'
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
    print the_page
```

in solr i have a schema defined which accepts id and title. i tried using postman chrome extension to send data to the url

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/venue/update/json?commit=true
```

with data

```
[{'id':'2','title':'test1'}]
```

and it gets indexed properly and is reflecting in solr. but if i run the python code on terminal i get the following output

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":6}}
```

which actually means that the data is getting indexed but on the solr when i try to search it with *:* query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/venue/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true
```

it does not show me the id:3 record.

am i doing something wrong in my code? please help
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
req.add_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
```

You need to set the header for the content in you req object. Please use the above statement just before calling the `urllib2.urlopen(req)`;